# C# how to get the IP address from the sockaddr

Tags: sockets, hook, pinvoke, ip-address, intptr

I hook the [connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx) function using [deviare](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/) , and C#. the issue is I need to get the IP Address from the sockaddr(which is the second param in the connect function) .

I checked the answers:
[C# sockaddr to sockaddr_in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732189/c-sharp-sockaddr-to-sockaddr-in)
 &
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17430748/3312744

I tried to use them. But I face a problem of getting the IntPtr from the connect function. 
I tried the following:

```
IParam pm = callInfo.Params.get_Item(1);

IntPtr sock = new IntPtr(pm.Value) ;

IPAddress ip_ader = ConvertSockAddrPtrToIPAddress(sock);
```

the  ConvertSockAddrPtrToIPAddress is a method used in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17430748/3312744    but an exception always thrown.

the exception is (The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x531a0858, on thread 0x724. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.)

Sorry for the weak English. Thank you in advance

Comment: Typically it's inet_ntop, but I'm not sure about C# having access to that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805843(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Actually this(stackoverflow.com/a/17430748/3312744) code for the inet and how to make it in C#. the problem I don't know how to get the Ptr to sockaddr. this(stackoverflow.com/a/11732261/3312744) answer if I know how to make it will solve it

Comment: The question can be (How to get an IntPtr which points to a sockaddr structure from a P/Invoked native function (such as connect)?) –